# How to send the id if the form is generated dynamically?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a MySql table:

```
id   concept
-------------
1    item1
2    item2
3    item3
```

I try to generate this table dynamically in the hmtl (I am not sure if I did it well):

```
<form action="extern.php" method="post">
<?php  
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM MyTable');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<input type="text" name="<?php echo $row["concept"] ?>"
value="<?php echo $row["concept"] ?>"><br>

<?php 
}
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This gives in the source of the html:

```
<form action="extern.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="item1" value="item1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="item2" value="item2"><br>
    <input type="text" name="item3" value="item3"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>
```

Then I put the php in the extern.php. And here comes my question:
How can I know the id of each input to match the concept in the update?

```
$id = $_POST["something"];  // how should I do this var?
$concept = $_POST["something"]; // how should I do this var?

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE MyTable 
                   SET concept = '$concept'
                   WHERE id = $id");
```

(I am sorry if this question is too basic. I really have tried a lot of things and look a lot of places. I am learning. Any help would be appreciated)

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0):

name of the input field will be combination of name and id like 
concept_id

for example

```
 <form action="" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="item1_21" value="item1"><br>
     <input type="text" name="item2_22" value="item2"><br>
     <input type="text" name="item3_23" value="item3"><br>
     <input type="submit" name="send">
 </form>
```

then on extern.php explode post key by  underscore

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){        
  if(preg_match('/[_]/i', $key )){
     $postArr = explode('_', $key);
  }
}
```

when you print $postArr you will get result something like below

```
 array (size=2)
  { 0 => string 'item1' (length=5)
    1=> string '21'
  }
```

now you have both the values to  update

```
 $concept = $postArr[0] 
 $id = $postArr[1] 

 mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE MyTable 
               SET concept = '$concept'
               WHERE id = $id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the names by looping over the keys for the array… but don't.

You are using the same value for the `name` and the `value`, so give them all the same name, and then loop over that.

```
<input type="text" name="item[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["concept"]); ?>">
```

(The `[]` is due to a quirk of PHP that requires duplicate names to end in `[]` before it will inflate to an array instead of dropping all but one of them)

Then you can loop over:

```
foreach ($_POST['item'] as $item) {
     # Do something with $item
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your answer. If I copy paste your code and echo $item; gives me item1item2item3 I do not see why it is useful? In other words, in my example what would be $id and $concept ?

Comment: item1 et al are your concept and your ID (they are the same in the HTML you were writing in your question).

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand how to get the id from your code